# Including <thread> results in the following compile error: 'fabsl': is not a member of '`global namespace'

Tags: c++, include

For the long time, standard libraries were giving me headache by throwing compilation errors simply by including them. For the long time, I've gone around it by reimplementing the parts that I needed, or with some #define for cstdio.

Now I need to include the  library, and I don't really see any ways around it. Yet again, I see no way of doing it either - any clues of dealing with that? I have tried the following:

```
#ifndef _CRT_FUNCTIONS_REQUIRED
#define _CRT_FUNCTIONS_REQUIRED 1
#endif // !_CRT_FUNCTIONS_REQUIRED
#include <thread>
```

And a few such variations, but to no avail.

EDIT - fixed:
I had created a "Math.h" header, breaking any headers relying on the standard C++ library "math.h". After renaming the header (and it's references) the code compiled.

Comment: Your question lacks some details (like which compiler/platform) but *maybe* a `using std::fabsl;` line before the offending `#include...` would work, if your compiler is putting the C runtime stuffs in the `std::` namespace.

Comment: Please create a [mcve], including just enough code to showcase the problem and a complete description of your compiler and its options.

Comment: I am using the MSVC compiler, building for Windows. Working on the minimal example.

Comment: Either something is broken in your compiler installation or the code is doing something that you haven't shown. From your first sentence, though, it certainly looks like something is wrong with the compiler installation.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, will try to be more detailed in the future.
Trying to reproduce the minimal reproducible example, with little success, I finally managed to guess the issue - my choice of naming a file the same as one contained in the standard C++ library. I'm a dumbo. Thanks for steering me towards finding this @alterigel

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I had created a Math.h header file. Renaming it fixed the problem.

It appears to be a good idea to avoid using file names from the C++ standard library, who would've said it.

Comment: Yeah, that's playing with fire. And if it's literally "Math.h", with a capital letter, it probably wouldn't be a problem on Unix systems, but would be trouble on Windows. The difference is that Unix file systems are case-sensitive, so "Math.h" and "math.h" name two different files. On Windows they're the same file.